# Mono for Android Texting/Email

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Texting and Email is not documented for Android but for iOS it is, Does anyone know where the code is documented or could tell me? Thank you!

Comment: Where is the existing documentation? What kind of documentation are you looking for? You haven't shown any explanation of the kinds of searching you've been doing, or where you've looked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing your terms - MonoTouch is the old name for Xamarin.iOS.  Mono for Android is the old name for Xamarin.Android.  Presumably you're asking "how do I send mail and texts with Xamarin.Android?"

Send an e-mail: http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/networking/email/send_an_email

Send a text: http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/networking/sms/send_an_sms